# Converting a single row to multiple rows

Tags: java, arrays, excel, loops, apache-poi

I want to Transformer stage to convert a single row for data with repeating columns to multiple output rows.

When the input data contains rows with multiple columns containing repeating data, how I can use the Transformer stage to produce multiple output rows: one for each of the repeating columns.
**Input:**

```
Col1    Col2    Name1   Name2   Name3

abc     def     Jim     Bob     Tom
```

[image: Input]

**Output:**

```
Col1    Col2    Name

abc     def     Jim

abc     def     Bob

abc     def     Tom
```

[image: output]

```
//loop to read data and store in array

for(i = 0; i <= Lastrow; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j <= R_endColumn; j++) {
        Row readrow = sheet.getRow(i);
        Cell readcell = readrow.getCell(j);
        String datavalues = df.formatCellValue(readcell);
        System.out.println(datavalues);
        localstore[i][j] = datavalues;
    }
}
int newrow_Number = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= Lastrow; i++) {
    for(int k = 0; k <= Lengthof_IP; k++) {
        newrow_Number = newrow_Number + 1;
        for(j = 0; j <= requirement_endColumn; j++) {
            Row readrow = sheet.createRow(newrow_Number);
            Cell readcell = readrow.getCell(j, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            String datavalues = df.formatCellValue(readcell);
            readcell.setCellValue(localstore[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/DataTransformation/op1.xlsx"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: In Excel (2010+) you can use `Power Query` or `Get & Transform` to unpivot the Name columns.

Comment: Can you post some more code? Do you want the output in the same file? Do you need to replace the original text? Are just the first two columns that are repeated? What was the output you got when you ran the code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by following code.

```
        filepath="C:/DataTransformation/Book1_New1.xlsx";
            File file = new File(filepath);

             filepath = file.getPath();

            //File file = new File("C:/Input/Programfiles/TestStepTable.xlsx");
                System.out.println(filepath);
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filepath);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);



                DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
                int Lastrow= sheet.getLastRowNum();
                int k = requirement_endColumn;
                System.out.println("Column for requirement: " + k);
                ArrayList myList = (ArrayList) new ArrayList();
                ArrayList myList1 = (ArrayList) new ArrayList();

                int lengthofInput= input_endColumn-input_startColumn;
                int lengthofOutput= output_endColumn-output_startColumn;
                int Lengthofloop;

                if(lengthofInput>=lengthofOutput)
                {
                    Lengthofloop=lengthofInput;
                }
                else
                {
                    Lengthofloop=lengthofOutput;
                }
                int i;
                int j;
                String[][] localstore= new String[100][100]; 
                //java.util.Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                for ( i = 0; i <=Lastrow; i++) // Change this max value of i upto total row number in the file
                { 

                    for ( int kk = 0; kk <=Lengthofloop; kk++) // Change this max value of i upto total row number in the file
                    {
                    newrow_Number=newrow_Number+1;
                    for ( j = 0; j <=output_endColumn; j++) // Change this max value of i upto total row number in the file
                    {

                    Row readrow= sheet.getRow(i);
                    //Row writerow=sheet.getRow(i+j);
                    Cell readcell=readrow.getCell(j,  org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    //Cell writecell=writerow.getCell(i+j);
                    String datavalues = df.formatCellValue(readcell);

                    //writecell.setCellValue(""+datavalues);

                //  System.out.println(datavalues);
                    localstore[i][j]= datavalues;
                    System.out.println("I am i"+i + "---"+ "I am J"+j+localstore[i][j]);

                //readrow= sheet.createRow(newrow_Number+1);
                //readcell=readrow.getCell(j,  org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                //readcell.setCellValue("sanjay"+localstore[i][j]);
                //Cell readcell=readrow.getCell(j, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                    }
                }
                }


                int jj=0;

            for ( i = 0; i <=Lastrow; i++) // Change this max value of i upto total row number in the file
                { 

                    for ( int kk = 0; kk <=Lengthofloop; kk++) // Change this max value of i upto total row number in the file
                    { 
                //newrow_Number=newrow_Number+1;
                Row readrow=sheet.createRow(newrow_Number);
                    for ( j = 0; j <=requirement_endColumn+2; j++) // Change this max value of i upto total row number in the file
                    {
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        int m = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                        System.out.println("getPhysicalNumberOfRows"+m);
                        Cell readcell=readrow.getCell(j+output_endColumn, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                        String datavalues = df.formatCellValue(readcell);
                        readcell.setCellValue(""+localstore[i][j]);
                        if(j==requirement_endColumn+1)
                        {
                            //readcell=readrow.getCell(j+jj, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                            readcell.setCellValue(""+localstore[i][j+kk]);
                            jj=jj+1;
                        }
                        else if(j==requirement_endColumn+2)
                        {
                            //readcell=readrow.getCell(j+jj, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                            readcell.setCellValue(""+localstore[i][output_startColumn+kk]);
                            jj=jj+1;
                            //sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(newrow_Number));

                        }

                    }

                }   
                    //newrow_Number=newrow_Number+1;
                }
            //sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(4));

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/DataTransformation/op1.xlsx"));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();

}
```